# Need r_member_social permissions for my App

Tags: linkedin-api

We are creating a Marketing dapp in which we need to track engagement and impression of a public post of influencer and for which we need r_member_social permissions, as we already have a developer account named socialX with product access of marketing developer platform.

I need permissions of r_member_social

Answer (score 0):

as per their official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/lms-faq?view=li-lms-2022-11#how-do-i-get-access-to-r_member_social), they are not accepting access requests this time due to resource constraints.

[image]